# 'bin/magento setup:upgrade' Failing after update

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, sql, magento2.2, setup-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from **2.1.9** to **2.2.0**.

I have updated my **composer.json** file and have successfully run composer update. Have successfully upgraded from **2.1.6** to **2.1.9** but keep getting the below error going from **2.1.9** to **2.2.0**.

```
[root@lmwebserver mageliveNOV]# php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/mageliveNOV/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/mageliveNOV/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/mageliveNOV/generated/code/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/html/mageliveNOV/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Aitoc_OrdersExportImport':
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Ebizmarts_AutoResponder':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Ebizmarts_Mandrill':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Upgrading schema.. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 , query was: ALTER TABLE `eav_attribute_group` ADD UNIQUE `CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CODE` (`attribute_set_id`,`attribute_group_code`)
[root@lmwebserver mageliveNOV]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento try alter the table `eav_attribute_group` to add a `unique` constraint on `attribute_set_id` and `attribute_group_code` columns. If this query fail, I suppose it's because you would have an entry (or more) which doesn't respect this constraint.

I think you could find out those entries by executing this query :

```
SELECT count(1) as counter, attribute_group_id, attribute_group_code
FROM pilot.eav_attribute_group
GROUP BY attribute_group_id, attribute_group_code
ORDER BY counter DESC;
```

Good luck !